# jQuery - Dynamically added element not working on mouseleave, click events

Tags: jquery

I have below div with class 'saved-wishlist',

```
<div class="saved-wishlist">
    <i class="fas fa-wishlist"></i>
    <a href="#" id="A123" class="remove-from-wishlist">
        Saved to Wish List</a>
</div>
```

On hover of anchor with class 'remove-from-wishlist', I'm updating the html of 'saved-wishlist' div ,

jQuery

```
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.remove-from-wishlist', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('.saved-wishlist').html($("#tooltip_remove_content").html()); //Gets html from other div and updates html of 'saved-wishlist' div
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.remove-from-wishlist', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        //some jQuery code
    });
```

Now, div with class 'saved-wishlist' looks like,

```
<div class="saved-wishlist">
        <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
        <a href="#" id="A123" class="remove-from-wishlist">
            Remove from Wish List</a>
</div>
```

Two issues I'm facing,

1. On the newly added anchor tag, when I mouse cursor away from it, the mouseleave function is not getting called, instead mouseenter gets fired .
2. On click of the newly added anchor tag, nothing happens , I have the below code,

   ```
    $(document).on('click','.remove-from-wishlist',function(){
        //some jQuery code 
    });
   ```

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: Since you're replacing the HTML of the whole `saved-wishlist` element, the `remove-from-wishlist` element is deleted. You can't get a mouseleave event on an element that no longer exists.

Comment: The newly added html to 'saved-wishlist' div contains 'remove-from-wishlist' element.

Comment: <div class="saved-wishlist">
    <!-- new html - begin -->
        <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
        <a href="#" id="A123" class="remove-from-wishlist"> <!-- remove-from-wishlist -->
            Remove from Wish List</a>
    <!-- new html - end -->        
</div>

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you simply want to have a icon and text toggle effect on mouseenter/mouseleave... And then an action on click.

This can all be done with just one event handler and without squarely replacing the HTML.

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave click", ".remove-from-wishlist", function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if(e.type === "mouseenter"){
    $this.text("Remove from Wish List");
    $this.prev().toggleClass("fa-heart fa-minus-circle");
  }
  
  if(e.type === "mouseleave"){
    $this.text("Saved to Wish List")
    $this.prev().toggleClass("fa-heart fa-minus-circle");
  }
  
  if(e.type === "click"){
    console.log("Do something to remove the entry from wish list here.");
    // Additional code here...
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="saved-wishlist">
  <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  <a href="#" id="A123" class="remove-from-wishlist">
    Saved to Wish List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When I hover, the text changes but strangely my css for fontawesome (fas fa-minus-circle) is not getting applied - blank square box . 
When I leave, the text changes - that's good, but new css for fontawesome is not applied, instead the css for icon defined in mouseenter 
    is getting applied (fas fa-minus-circle). 
Click works

Comment: Make sure you use the right `fa-__` classes.

Comment: I double checked, class names are correct, On mouseleave, fas fa-minus-circle icon displays, even though that's not valid.

Comment: You should have `$this.prev().toggleClass("fa-wishlist fa-minus-circle");` in both mouse enter and leave. `.toggleClass()` adds or removes the classes. -- Notice that I used `fa-heart` because `fa-wishlist` was not working for the demo.

Comment: You are correct. Added this $this.prev().toggleClass("fas fa-minus-circle fas fa-wishlist"); and it displayed the correct icon and also the square box  problem solved, since fas in both places. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Louys, Thanks for your help. In this case, using toggleClass and updating text, solved the problem. I have one more similar use case, where the replaced html is slightly complex, would you mind providing an answer for my original request.

Comment: Sorry, I moved the <i> tag within the <a> , tried '$this.children('i').toggleClass("fas fa-minus-circle fas fa-wishlist");' , but it's not picking up the i element.

Comment: The changing the text of the `<a>` with `.text()` will remove the `<i>` element. So if you want the `<i>` inside, you have to use a `<span>` for the text and use `$this.find("span").text("the text here")`